# Output location Batch File

Tags: batch-file, command-line, batch-processing

I need to know how to Prompt a user for an output location (IP address and shared folder name) and then map a drive letter to that location with a batch file. any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `set /p` (http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) then lookup the `net use` command.

Comment: Do you have any code to work with?

Answer (score 0):

I shall first give the complete code and then explain what each portion does.

Here is the complete code (note, the mapping is not persistent so you will have to run this again on reboot):

```
@echo off
set /p drive=map to (drive letter. ex: Z:):
set /p ip=I.P address:
set /p dir=directory:
net use %drive% "\\%ip%\%dir%"
```

Now, for the explanation:

`@echo off` makes sure the commands are run and not just printed.

`set /p ip=I.P address:` prompts the user with `I.P address:` and stores the information recieved in the variable `%ip%`(this works for all of the `set /p` commands). Thus the use of the command is `set /p varname=prompt`.

`net use %drive% "\\%ip%\%dir%"` maps the network drive using the variables that the user has just entered (inclosed with `%` as arguments). The arguments are:

`net use drivename "\\ipaddress\directory_of_network_drive"`

Also, don't forget to mark this as the answer if you've found it useful.